# Only VSC light is ON without the TRAC OFF light after replacing clockspring, what is missing?

Tags: toyota, corolla, esp-esc

Had to replace the airbag and clockspring on a 2014-16 model year corolla due to a minor parking lot hit.

This car has all the bells and whistles in it along with steering wheel controls.

The VSC and TPMS lights were on after the repair. Took it to the dealership, the Code extracted there is C1433-SAS internal circuit. But now only the VSC light is on and no other lights are on.

How can that be when the clock spring is just replaced(with a part salvaged from a car which did not have its airbags blown)?

Also, don't we need to have both the VSC and TPMS lights ON, to have a faulty steering angle sensor?
ABS light is OFF when stationary or even while driving on curved surfaces. There is no indication of ABS being engaged via the pedals.

Do I really need a zero point calibration to fix this as there is no change in the front end geometry. 
Am I overlooking some detail here?
Do I really need a new Clockspring with SAS to resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model/engine/trans of the vehicle in question?

Comment: Thank you.  Its a  2015/Toyota/Corolla/1.8L/CVT with a sunroof. So its a Corolla S variant.

Comment: Why would you need to have a tpms light on for a faulty SAS? Was the abs module the only module scanned for codes? It sounds like the sensor may have been installed incorrectly or was damaged during installation. You say a used part was installed was there anything to prevent the clocksping and sensor assembly from spinning?  Is everything plugged in? Either way a calibration needs to be done when installing a new sensor. You also need to post more data. The code sets when the skid control ecu receives an invalid signal from the SAS module. Does the module have power and ground?

Comment: Does the skid control ecu show a sas signal? Why was a used part installed? What happened to the old part? What did the dealer recommend? Replacing the whole assembly?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. There was an airbag replacement, so went ahead and changed this clockspring at the same time. Now the dealer recommends replacing the whole assembly because of that code.

Comment: I will follow your suggestions and post the observations. Thank you once again.